# Hibernate - n+1 select queries with  1-to-1

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Organization is mapped to Address as 1-to-1:

**Organization**:

```
<one-to-one class="Address" constrained="true" name="address" property-ref="organizationId"/>
```

**Address**:

```
<many-to-one class="Organization"  name="organization">
          <column name="OrganizationID" not-null="false" unique="true"/>
  </many-to-one>
```

this query generates addtitional select for every Organization + 1:

```
   query = session.createQuery("select o from Organization as o where o.isCool=0").setReadOnly(true);
   organizations = query.list();
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html tells to `fetch="join"` but this doesn't make any difference. How to solve this problem? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
In debugger i can see that address is actually not lazy loaded, i have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using an HQL to fetch your stuff, it would not help to simply use the annotation or the attribute that you are trying, to avoid the n+1 problem.

The right solution would be to make use of 'FETCH JOIN' clause in your query. You can follow the following link for more details:
http://www.realsolve.co.uk/site/tech/hib-tip-pitfall.php?name=n1selects

Comment: Thanks for response. But is its efficient to keep all this fetched data in memory and not using it? I don't mind not using hql. So i need to use criteria?

Comment: You can continue using HQL. In fact, It will still fetch you only the required stuff (records where condition o.isCool=0 is true) but without doing n+1 fetches - that is if you use the FETCH JOIN clause.

Comment: please bear with me, i don't quite understand. So you're saying that fetch join will not initialize addresses?

Comment: Aah, probably I get it better now. You are worried about the associated records being fetched along with the parent object? If that is your problem, then it has not much to do with the n+1 issue.
You should use LAZY fetching so that Hibernate would not get you the actual associated objects.

Please correct me if am wrong, I'd be happy to clarify/help further.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, i am really new to programming. I'm already using lazy fetching (its turned on by default, right?). So it's either n+1 selects and having proxies, or fetch join to initialize associated addresses even if i don't need them? Memory usage versus speed?

Comment: Well, what is it that you want to achieve? 
If you are looking for memory savings, then LAZY fetch (yes it's the default) will help you.
That is because, Hibernate would not fetch the child records while fetching the parent. Instead, it would just provide a PROXY object in place of the associated object. It's only when you try to do a 'get' on the associated object(s), it is that Hibernate will fire a query to get the associated child objects.

Comment: In debugger i can see that address is actually not lazy loaded, i have no idea why. Could you help me, please.